# How to get out .sln- or .csprojfile names and use them as a Condition?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am working with a few different .sln files (that is connected to their own .csproj file in iOS) depending on what project i would like to run in my solution in Visual Studio. In order to work with the different projects I need a way to know what .sln (or .csproj) file is currently "running".

Currently my project is filled with `Condition`s:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugAppNameOne|iPhone' ">
```

What i was thinking of doing is to replace that `Condition` and instead somehow get out the name of either the .sln-or the .csprojfile that is running. My question is, would that be possible and if so how would i get out their names? What i'm thinking is something along these lines:

.sln:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" ’$(TheSlnName)|' == 'SolutionName.AppNameOne.sln'">
```

.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" ’$(TheCsProjName)|' == 'SolutionName.iOS.AppNameOne.csproj'">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `.sln` files, you can use the following msbuild Macros to figure out what solution you have opened:

```
$(SolutionFileName): MySolution.sln
$(SolutionPath): D:\MyProjects\MySolution.sln
$(SolutionDir): D:\MyProjects\
$(SolutionName): MySolution
```

You should be able to use:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(SolutionFileName)' == 'SolutionName.AppNameOne.sln'">
```

For `.csproj` files, you can use the following Macros:

```
$(ProjectFileName): MyLogic.csproj
$(ProjectPath): D:\MyProjects\MyLogic\MyLogic.csproj
$(ProjectDir): D:\MyProjects\MyLogic\
$(ProjectName): MyLogic
```

You should be able to use:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(ProjectFileName)' == 'SolutionName.iOS.AppNameOne.csproj' ">
```

You can view MSBuild macros available to your project by viewing the project properties, selecting the Build Events tab, and click on "Edit Pre-Build..." or "Edit Post-Build...". In the window that appears, select the "Macros >>" button, and you'll able to see relevant MSBuild Macro info you could use and what it would evaluate to.

You can also view MSBuild macro [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).

Comment: Thx a lot. I will try it out asap!